# why i am getting invalid syntax error def swap(self,(x1,y1),(x2,y2)):

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an invalid syntax error for the below code at (x1,y1)

```
def swap(self,(x1,y1),(x2,y2)):
```

invalid syntax error

Comment: What are you passing into the function? Please post the code for the `swap` function as well

Comment: Is this valid syntax? I mean tuple on the arguments, I never saw that

Comment: I can't remember too much about Python, but I don't think you can add a tuple in the definition (you'd have to do `def swap(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):` instead)

Comment: `self, (x1,y1),(x2,y2)`, this is not valid argument expression

Comment: That syntax was removed somewhere in the 3.x series.  You have to write it as `def swap(self, x1y1, x2y2):` now, and separately do `x1, y1 = x1y1; x2, y2 = x2y2` to split them apart.

Comment: @jasonharper do you know the name of this? I never saw something like that, is a kind of parameter destructing?

Comment: Ohh I found: here is the removal https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is no longer valid syntax in Python. What you can do instead is just treat each individual tuple as its own parameter, and then extract the values you need directly from those tuples inside the body of your method.

```
def swap(self, point1, point2):
    x1, y1 = point1
    x2, y2 = point2
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Good point @pppery. I've edited my response appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the function call with the * operator to unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple. That seems to be what your trying to do and might be the issue with your syntax error.

[Refrence](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)

```
list(range(3, 6))            # normal call with separate arguments

[3, 4, 5]

args = [3, 6]

list(range(*args))            # call with arguments unpacked from a list

[3, 4, 5]
```